# Spark: Which is the proper way to use a Broadcast variable?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I don't know if I'm using well a broadcast variable.

I have two RDDs, `rdd1` and `rdd2`. I want to apply `rdd2.mapPartitionsWithIndex(...)`, and for each partition I need to perfom some calculation using the whole `rdd1`. So, I think this is a case to use a Broadcast variable. **First question:** *Am I thinking it right?*

To do so, I did this:

```
val rdd1Broadcast =  sc.broadcast(rdd1.collect())
```

**Second question:** *Why do I need to put `.collect()`.* I saw examples with and without `.collect()`, but I didn't realized when do I need to use it.

Also, I did this:

```
val rdd3 = rdd2.mapPartitionsWithIndex( myfunction(_, _, rdd1Broadcast), preservesPartitioning = preserves).cache()
```

**Third question:** *Which is better: passing `rdd1Broadcast` or `rdd1Broadcast.value`?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I thinking it right?

There is really not enough information to answer this part. Broadcasting is useful only if broadcasted object is relatively small, or local access significantly reduces computational complexity.

> Why do I need to put .collect().

Because `RDDs` can be accessed only on the driver. Broadcasting `RDD` is not meaningful, as you cannot access the data from a task.

> Which is better: passing `rdd1Broadcast` or `rdd1Broadcast.value`?

The argument should be of type `Broadcast[_]` so don't use `rdd1Broadcast.value`. If parameter is passed by value, it will be evaluated and substituted locally, and `broadcast` will not be used.

Comment: I thought broadcasting is useful for big amount of data... so I was wrong with that.
About your second comment, it's not clear for me.. could you add more information? Thank you!

Comment: To broadcast object it has to fit in memory of each node, so it is suitable for large objects. And the second point - you just cannot use `RDD` outside driver and any transformations are executed on the workers.

Comment: Oh, I see, I was confusing because of your comment: `Broadcasting is useful only if broadcasted object is relatively small`. Thank you!